# Random Array Sorting

Tags: arrays, sorting

Is it possible to sort (ascending) the randomly generated integer array for the following code? If, so how?

import java.util.Random;

public class RandomArraySorter {

```
        public static void main(String args[]){
        Random random = new Random();

        int array[] = new int[10];

        //number of integer spaces within the array:
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        //random numbers from 1 to 100:
        array[i] = random.nextInt(100) + 1;

           System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
    } //end of main
} //end of class
```

Answer (score 2):

You can sort with:

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```